# I am trying to get Header info from Request Controller and read into IntegrationFlow

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I wanted to understand where is best location to read headers and use them inside my IntegrationFlow layer.

ServiceController.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/integration")
public class ServiceController {
    @Autowired
    private ServiceGateway gateway;
    
    @GetMapping(value = "info")
    public String info() {
        return gateway.info();
    }
}
```

ServiceGateway.java

```
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Gateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;

@MessagingGateway
public interface ServiceGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "integration.info.gateway.channel")
    public String info();
}
```

ServiceConfig.java

```
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.IntegrationComponentScan;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.http.dsl.Http;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class ServiceConfig {
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow info() throws URISyntaxException {
        String uri = "http://localhost:8081/hellos/simpler";
        return IntegrationFlows.from("integration.info.gateway.channel")
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway(uri).httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST).expectedResponseType(String.class)).get();
    }
}
```

From Consumer I am receiving some Header meta data. I want to know in above flow whether it is good idea from following approaches:

1. Read headers in Controller and then pass through into my IntegrationFlow: For this I am not aware how to pass through.
2. Is there best or any way exist to read request headers into IntegrationFlow layer?

For this second approach I have tried below code but runtime I am getting error as channel is one way and hence stopping the flow.

```
return IntegrationFlows.from("integration.info.gateway.channel").handle((request) -> {
            MessageHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
            System.out.println("-----------" + headers);
        }).handle(Http.outboundGateway(uri).httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST).expectedResponseType(String.class)).get();
```

My problem is how to send request parameters from incoming call to carry those internally invoking another rest call. Here I wanted to transform the data from request headers and construct into new json body and then send this to `http://localhost:8081/hellos/simpler` URL.

The flow:

[image]

I am trying to construct this RequestBody before sending to internal REST POST call:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gateway method with no paylaod is for receiving data, not requesting it.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway-calling-no-argument-methods

Add a `@Header` annotated parameter to the gateway.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway-configuration-annotations

```java
@MessagingGateway
public interface ServiceGateway {
    
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "integration.info.gateway.channel")
    public String info("", @Header("x-api") String xApi);

}
```

This will send a message with an empty string as the payload with the header set.

Comment: Hey @Gary Thanks for your help, but my next questions is how can I get those Header properties inside IntegrationFlow method, is that make implicit available, or how to fetch ?

Comment: And from Controller how should I pass this Header value ?

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-http-headers add a `@RequestHeader` parameter to get the headers. Pass the header you want in the gateway parameter. You already have code to access the message headers in the handler.